# How to create an ics-File?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios4

I want to make a app which can create a new event and send it to other persons.
So I thought it might be possible to create an ics-File of an EKEvent and send it away via email.

But I don't know how to create such a file from an EKEvent.
How does it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no methods of EKEvent which allows you to save it to file. The only way I see is to create file on your own, it should have VCalendar format. Just save event to file from iCal and see what it has inside.

Comment: I have a problem by sending such a file. I uses the following code: [controller addAttachmentData:testData mimeType:@"text/calendar" fileName:@"Meeting File.ics"];  But I only see a "htm" file in the EMail, when i received it.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose I'm late, but... I found a category that converts an EKEvent to an .ics file. I haven't tested yet: https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/EKEventToiCal

Answer (score 0):

Late answer:

The file format is defined here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt  Since this is the official definition, it is a long document.