# Generate .ics file on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, eventkit, icalendar

I'm building ios application that must generate .ics file from iPhone Calendar, but can't found solution for it. As I see EventKit Framework doesn't give this functionality, maybe some other frameworks/libs can do it?

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290484/how-to-create-an-ics-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find link [here](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/EKEventToiCal) for a project which perform this. But i haven't tested